Docker compose: how to append a property of my application properties in docker compose
Hi I rewriting my application properties in my docker compose I want to know how I can append to already existing file instead of overriding the properties.
wishlist-service:
    image: tejajagadeep/movie-app-wishlist-service:latest
    container_name: wishlist-container
    environment:
      - eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://eureka-server:8761/eureka
      - spring.config.import=optional:configserver:http://config-server:8888/
      - management.zipkin.tracing.endpoint=http://zipkin-server:9411/api/v2/spans
      - swagger.server.url=http://localhost:8769/,http://localhost:4200/
      - spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://root:root1234@mongodb:27017/wishlistdb?authSource=admin
    ports:
      - "8082:8082"
    networks:
      - my-movie-network

I want to append this property instead of overwriting it.
- swagger.server.url=http://localhost:8769/,http://localhost:4200/, + values


Where those new values currently coming from? Are they server specific constants (or otherwise available before docker build - if yes, how)?

Btw: you should use httpS. Recent browsers tries to stop you when you open an http website!

This is spring boot application these are constants of the service which I am overrating

Docker Compose does not provide a built-in method for appending to environment variables within the Compose file itself. Each environment variable you define in a service's environment section in the docker-compose.yml file defines that environment variable within the Docker container when it is run, and if the variable already exists it will be overwritten.
Configuration in the Application Code
If you have control over the application code, consider writing it such that the application can read both the swagger.server.url environment variable and another variable, like additional.swagger.server.urls. Your application can then combine and use these two values as needed.
After that, in your Docker Compose file, you define swagger.server.url like before and define additional.swagger.server.urls for extra values.
Shell Script
You could write a startup script for the Docker container that combines the values of multiple environment variables into one. This shell script could be executed when the Docker container starts.

Thank you, I already considered these but I liked to know if there were any available. Thanks for confirming them

Or just read the values, combine with new values, then override. It should be possible, isn't it?

I meant skipping the additional config, because if you know those values in advance (so they are constant), why to put them to additional instead of the original? Did you mean additional to be computer/server specific?

I am the developer of the project so I know the config but what about others

Who else needs to change docker config and for what reason and why they need different address?

Changing port number in the compose
